# How to suppress notice when running VsCode Development Container postCreateCommand

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, devcontainer

I am using the postCreateCommand in a devcontainer.json and would like to suppress the notice that lists the command(s) being executed post container creation. When opening the development container using the devcontainer.json VsCode shows a notice indicating that the command has been run and shows the output. The user must then press any key.

[PostCreateCommand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpPpv.png)

Comment: Assuming the extension does something similar to the CLI (Not sure if it's using that code).
You can try to disable all output on your post command.
Or change the extension log level in settings.
https://github.com/devcontainers/cli/blob/main/src/spec-shutdown/dockerUtils.ts#L345

Comment: Did you find an answer to that? I am stuck on it for several days...